# Integrating notes from native iPhone notes app

Tags: ios

Is it possible to integrate notes from native iPhone notes app? 
I surfed over and also looked in the Apple Documentation but no luck.
If anyone has tried then please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [EventKit framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) grants access to users **Calendar app** and **Reminders app** information. However there is no API or framework that allows us to access the Notes app so as of now it is not possible.